# what is numClasses in to_categorial keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

so I just learn CNN and I found really helpful website , pyimagesearch and I found how to make CNN model for training an image but I found an error and the author gave solution but I do not understand his solution , I already ask again but but he does not response, here is his code

`lb =  LabelEncoder()
trainY = lb.fit_transform(trainY)
testY = to_categorical(testY, numClasses)`

I do not understand what numClasses is can someone explain it to me thanks

Comment: Its the number of classes

Comment: if i have 2 class so numClasses is 2? sorry for dumb question

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: and sorry for one more question , i change numClasses to 2 but i get this error, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'beef' can u explain me why i get this error ,thank you

Comment: you have to convert your classes to numbers

Comment: how can i do it? i know my question so dumb , i really need to know it

Answer (score 1):

`numClasses` is exactly number of classes in your training dataset. This value  defines the length of one-hot vectors. Let's see an example:

Assume that `y = [1,2,0,0]` are labels for 4 examples. The one-hot representation converts one dimensional array of labels into `2-D` array of the shape `(number_of_examples, numClasses)`. `Y`  contains 4 examples and 3 unique classes `(0,1,2)` so the one-hot representation is (for each example length of one-hot class representation has length 3):

`[[0,1,0],
 [0,0,1],
 [1,0,0],
 [1,0,0]]`

You've got the value error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'beef'` because your label are categorical (not integers)
You have to convert your categorical labels into integers. You can use for that 
pandas function https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html

Or using LabelsEncoder

```py
lb =  LabelEncoder()
trainY = lb.fit_transform(trainY)
testY = lb.transform(testY)
testY = to_categorical(testY, numClasses)
```

where `numClasses=max(testy)`

Comment: how can i use LabelEncode? i just copy paste from pyimagesearch , can u tell me? thank you so much

Comment: Please see documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html#preprocessing-targets

Comment: @bramastavikana I've modify my answer - you have to also transform your testY

Comment: ive tried ur code and i change numClasses into max(testY) but error appear ndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1 then i change it into 2 because i have 2 class but error appear again ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: What's the shape of your testY?

Comment: shape of testY is (150, 3072)